# many controller for state in ui-router

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

how to add many controller for state in ui-router ?

I have searched long and hard but found nothing that helped yet. Where I wrong? I really do not know what to do. I wrote all the details below. I've tried and did not succeed.

```
angular.module('uiRouterApp.typeNews', [
        'uiRouterApp.typeNews.Service',
        'ui.router'
    ])
    .config(
        [
            '$stateProvider', '$urlRouterProvider',
            function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {
                $stateProvider
                    .state('detail', {
                        url: '/typeNews/detail/typeNewsId=:typeNewsId',
                        templateUrl: '/Scripts/ui-route/typeNews/typeNews.detail.html',
                        controller: [
                            '$scope', '$stateParams', '$state', 'typeNewsService',
                            function($scope, $stateParams, $state, typeNewsService) {
                                typeNewsService.readTypeNews($stateParams.typeNewsId)
                                    .success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
                                        $scope.typeNews = data;
                                    });
                            }
                        ]
                    })
                    .state('typeNews', {
                        url: '/typeNews/PageSize=:PageSize/PageIndex=:PageIndex',
                        templateUrl: '/Scripts/ui-route/typeNews/typeNews.html',
                        controller: 'pagerCtrl'// need two many controller like controller: 'pagerCtrl' , 'gridCtrl'
                    });
            }
        ]
    );
```

Answer (score 0):

Every state in your state provider maps to a single controller.
Having multiple (many) controllers handling one state is not possible and goes against the basic concept of the framework.

I don't understand what you want to achieve with multiple controllers in one state.
What is your idea and how should this function? Can you explain?

You can have parent and child states and they can have their own controllers. Maybe that is what could help you out.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your comment:

> controller: 'pagerCtrl'// need two many controller like controller: 'pagerCtrl' , 'gridCtrl'

I think you want controllers for ui elements.  You probably want to use or create a Directive.  Have a look at [ngTable](https://github.com/esvit/ng-table) and [ng-Grid](http://angular-ui.github.io/ng-grid/) for example.

Answer (score 0):

Yes u will need this if u reference some other controllers info....just add one controller to the state and the other one u can nest it as a ng-controller in the html.

**JS snippet**

```
angular.module('xTimeApp').config(function ($stateProvider, $httpProvider) {
$stateProvider.state('editpayhistory', {
      url: '/payhistory/:id/edit',
      templateUrl: '../PayHist/PayHist-edit.html',
      controller: 'PayHistEditController'  //<-Controller 1
  });
```

**HTML snippet:**

```
<div class="form-group">
<div data-ng-controller="AttendanceListController">   <!--Controller 2 -->
    <label for="title" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Attendance</label>
    <!--Need to compare with same object type, so create an empty _attend object with the payhist id as the _attend id field-->
    <div class="col-sm-10">
        <select ng-init="payhist._attend = {AC_CODEID: payhist.AC_CODEID}"
                ng-change="payhist.AC_CODEID = payhist._attend.AC_CODEID"
                ng-model="payhist._attend"
                ng-options="attend.AC_CODEID as attend.AC_NAME for attend in attends track by attend.AC_CODEID"></select>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
.state('app.somestate', {
    url : '/someurl',
    views:{
        'menuContent': {
            templateUrl: 'part1.html',
            controller: 'ACtrl'
        },
        'otherContent': {
            templateUrl: 'part2.html',
            controller: 'BCtrl'
        },
        'someotherContent': {
            templateUrl: 'part3.html',
            controller: 'CCtrl'
        }
    }
})
```